# iOS email client testing

Tags: iphone, email, html-email, email-client, macos-mail-app

I made an email HTML template. It is developed using some tables with 2 columns.
If I watch this email with some clients in different devices everithing looks good. But if I watch the email with an iPhone (of my friend) my template become 1 column, images become bigger, tables with border and some other problems.
I don't have an apple device, so testing is very difficult. what I'm asking here is if exist a way to emulate the iOS mail client or other any suggestions are appreciate.
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look into using Google Chrome. It's based on webkit, an open source browser engine which is also what IOS uses to render emails.

When you use Inspect mode, it gives you a list of devices it can emulate. I can't verify right now that it's the same list for Windows or linux. It's close.

It's not a replacement for using actual devices or a services like Email on Acid or Litmus, but it gets you some feedback on how your design looks on other devices and it's free.

Good luck.

**Confirmed**: I finally got Windows 10 working and I can confirm that Google Chrome allows you to Inspect your code and emulate the look on an iPhone, iPad, Galaxy or Pixel device. You can customize to add specific devices (if available).

Comment: the way IOS handles email's in not 1:1 with how google chrome renders html. there is more limitations and strange edge cases. setting chrome to use a iphone resolution is not going to give you the strange webkit cases. litmus is the best way. just like browserstack is the way

Answer (score 3):

This is exactly what you are after:
https://litmus.com/email-testing

I have used this a lot! And it works really well!

Also, try and take a look at this:
https://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/

Really nice tool to check what's compatible in different e-mail clients.

Comment: And the downvote on this answer makes absolutely no sense. This is exactly what he is looking for, a way to test different e-mail clients without having the actual devices.

Comment: I didn't down vote but chrome is the easiest and no fee alternative to test how iPhones will render. If there was other devices involved in the question then yes this answer would have been the best one.

Comment: Thank you Syfer! And I agree, I didn't think about it that way, but of cause trying it out in a Webkit browser will give you a pretty good result. I was just thinking if you wanted to be 100% sure how it renders. - I am all new to Stack overflow, so it was a bit disencouraging to get downvoted on my first answer 